# Multiple entity framework DbContext still leads to concurrent exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

So, I am basically trying to make it so that I can run multiple tasks that each task has its own DbContext so that they don't cause an exception. So basically, like how ASP.NET async handlers work. Right now I'm do something to the effect of

```
// set up the unity container
// WON'T WORK the dbUnitOfWork will used in two tasks.
container.RegisterType<Framework.Data.IDbUnitOfWork, Framework.Data.EntityFramework.DbUnitOfWork>(Core.IoC.Lifetime.PerThread);
container.RegisterFactory<System.Data.Entity.DbContext, ContextFactory>(o => o.Create, Framework.Core.IoC.Lifetime.Transient);



AsyncContext.Run(() => app.Run());
// run the following code fragment with an Async Context from Nito



workers.AddRange(container.resolveAll<IWorker>());
foreach (var worker in workers) {
    tasks.add(worker.WorkAsync());
}
Tasks.WhenAll(tasks);
```

but what happens is that every time I keep getting this cursed "NotSupportedException" because of a second operation started on the same DbContext. I tried making my DbContext be PerThread in Unity, but that still didn't seem to work. The way I pulled of per thread (well hoping at least) is

```
Tasks.Run(() => worker.WorkAsync());
```

I just want to be able to run a group of tasks each with their own DbContext. So that they can all asynchronously do independent database operations. So how do I pull off this desired behavior.

Comment: What is IWorker and what does it in WorkAsync?

Comment: IWorker has 1 method WorkAsync that returns a Task.

Comment: How do you inject IDbUnitOfWork into the IWorker implementation? It would be easier if you just show us the code

Comment: I just do constructor based dependency injection the constructor looks like

WorkerConcrete(IDbUnitOfWork dbUnitOfWork) { this.dbUnitOfWork = dbUnitOfWork; }

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I have an idea that the cause of the issue might be that you defined `PerThread` lifetime of `IDbUnitOfWork` and injected it in the following line of code:

```
workers.AddRange(container.resolveAll<IWorker>());
```

So, you inject `IDbUnitOfWork` in the same main thread, and that's why you get the same instance.

Comment: Yes, but how do I fix it. IDK how to do like a PerHttpRequest that is used by ASP.NET.

Comment: If you just need separate IDbUnitOfWork instances, then use transient lifetime so that each resolve creates a new instance. Also, you can run separate threads and in each of them resolve IDbUnitOfWork (in this case PerThread will work). Also note that running async task doesn't mean, that it runs in a separate thread, actually they run in the same thread.